# Wordpress paginate_links() not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Using Wordpress 4.0.1

I have  query set up to echo out archive posts to a page.  Which works fine, here is the query.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => array($category[0]->cat_ID), // gets the category ID higher up in the code.
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);

if ($category[0]->cat_ID == 3) {

    $today = date('Ymd');                       
    if (!empty($year) && !empty($monthnum)) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_start',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value' => $today
            )
        );
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_start',
                'compare' => '>',
                'value' => $today
            )
        );
    }

    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['meta_key'] = 'event_start';

}

$the_query = new WP_Query( array_merge($wp_query->query, $args) );
```

I'm getting out the posts and then at the bottom I want a pagination feature.

Here is my pagination query

```
$args = array(
    'base'      => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'add_args'  => true,
    'format'    => '/page/%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text' => __('Next »'),
    'end_size'  => 3,
    'type'      => 'list'
);

echo paginate_links($args);
```

But whats happening is the link at the bottom is showing the url twice like this

```
http://domain.com/category/recent-seminars/page/2domain.com/category/recent-seminars/page/2/?future
```

This results in 'Nothing Found' (unsurprising), but even if I delete either the first half or second half, I still get nothing found.

I've tried loads of different combinations in the paginate_links query but nothing is working.

**EDIT**

I've amended the main query to this now

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => array($category[0]->cat_ID),                      
    'paged'     => $paged
);

$today = date('Ymd');

if ($category[0]->cat_ID == 3) {

    $args['meta_key'] = 'event_start';
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'event_start',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today
        )
    );
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';

}
```

This works for the first page, but as soon as I click one of the next page links, it stops working, however If i take out the `$args['meta_query']` array, the paging does work, but the posts are in the wrong order.

Comment: it seems your `base` is off. Did you try an example from the WP Reference? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: You could have added whether that worked or not, as your post states "nothing is working".